# dictionary function .popitem() is not returning random key-value pair

Tags: python

I have code where the .popitem() function is not returning random key-value pairs. Instead it is popping them sequentially from the last one back.
The function should be randomly dealing the "cards". Is there something I'm missing?

```
# This program uses a dictionary as a deck of cards

def main():
    # Create a deck of cards.
    deck = create_deck()

    # Get the number of cards to deal
    num_cards = int(input('How many cards should I deal? '))

    # Deal the cards
    deal_cards(deck, num_cards)

# The create_deck function returns a dictionary representing a deck of cards
def create_deck():
    
    deck = {'Ace of Spades':1, '2 of Spades':2, '3 of Spades':3, '4 of Spades':4, '5 of Spades':5,
            '6 of Spades':6, '7 of Spades':7, '8 of Spades':8, '9 of Spades':9, '10 of Spades':10,
            'Jack of Spades':10, 'Queen of Spades':10, 'King of Spades':10,
            'Ace of Hearts':1, '2 of Hearts':2, '3 of Hearts':3, '4 of Hearts':4, '5 of Hearts':5,
            '6 of Hearts':6, '7 of Hearts':7, '8 of Hearts':8, '9 of Hearts':9, '10 of Hearts':10,
            'Jack of Hearts':10, 'Queen of Hearts':10, 'King of Hearts':10,
            'Ace of Clubs':1, '2 of Clubs':2, '3 of Clubs':3, '4 of Clubs':4, '5 of Clubs':5,
            '6 of Clubs':6, '7 of Clubs':7, '8 of Clubs':8, '9 of Clubs':9, '10 of Clubs':10,
            'Jack of Clubs':10, 'Queen of Clubs':10, 'King of Clubs':10,
            'Ace of Diamonds':1, '2 of Diamonds':2, '3 of Diamonds':3, '4 of Diamonds':4, '5 of Diamonds':5,
            '6 of Diamonds':6, '7 of Diamonds':7, '8 of Diamonds':8, '9 of Diamonds':9, '10 of Diamonds':10,
            'Jack of Diamonds':10, 'Queen of Diamonds':10, 'King of Diamonds':10}

    return deck

# The deal_cards function deals a specified number of cards from the deck

def deal_cards(deck, number):
    # Initialize an accumulator for the hand value
    hand_value = 0

    # Make sure the number of cards to deal is not greater than the number of cards in the box
    if number > len(deck):
        number = len(deck)

    # Deal the cards and accumulate their values.
    for count in range(number):
        card, value = deck.popitem()
        print(card)
        hand_value += value

    # Display the value of the hand.
    print("Value of this hand:", hand_value)

main()
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? According to the documentation, in Python 3.7+, LIFO order is guaranteed. In previous versions, `popitem` would pop and return an "arbitrary" key-value pair, not a "random" one. Arbitrary != random. All that means is that the order in which items are popped are not explicitly specified by the standard. There's nothing necessarily "random" about it.

Comment: @PaulM. is there any way I can get it to return arbitrary pairs that simulate some sort of  randomness without having to resort to using the Random module to generate random numbers and using if statements to link the to the dictionary contents? I'm using 3.9.2

Comment: You can use the `random` module for a lot more than just creating random numbers. You could use `random.choice` to select a random key, and then pop the corresponding value from your dictionary. Personally, I wouldn't use a dictionary to store your cards in the first place. I would create a `Card` class, which has `Suit` and `Rank` enums. Your deck then becomes a list of card objects, which you can shuffle using `random.shuffle`. A list mimics the behavior of a deck of cards better than a dictionary, since elements in lists have a well-defined order, whereas keys in dictionaries do not.

Comment: @PaulM. Thanks I'll go that route

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I'm extending my comments with an answer.

You can use `random.choice` to select a random key, and then pop that key-value pair to get the corresponding value:

```
from random import choice

deck = {
    "ace of spades": 1,
    "two of spades": 2,
    "three of spades": 3,
    "four of spades": 4,
    "five of spades": 5
}

while deck:
    key = choice(list(deck))
    value = deck.pop(key)

    print("I popped '{}' and got {}".format(key, value))
```

Output:

```
I popped 'four of spades' and got 4
I popped 'five of spades' and got 5
I popped 'ace of spades' and got 1
I popped 'three of spades' and got 3
I popped 'two of spades' and got 2
>>>
```

Not really a fan of this approach, because you effectively have to iterate over all remaining keys each time you do `list(deck)`.

Or, using a `Card` class and a list of card-objects for a deck (instead of a dict):

```
from enum import Enum


class Suit(Enum):
    SPADES = 0
    HEARTS = 1
    CLUBS = 2
    DIAMONDS = 3


class Rank(Enum):
    TWO = 2
    THREE = 3
    FOUR = 4
    FIVE = 5
    SIX = 6
    SEVEN = 7
    EIGHT = 8
    NINE = 9
    TEN = 10
    JACK = 11
    QUEEN = 12
    KING = 13
    ACE = 14


class Card:

    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} of {}".format(self.rank.name.capitalize(), self.suit.name.capitalize())


def main():
    from random import shuffle
    
    deck = [Card(suit, rank) for suit in Suit for rank in Rank]
    shuffle(deck)

    while deck:
        print(deck.pop())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
Nine of Spades
Six of Hearts
King of Clubs
Eight of Diamonds
Queen of Spades
Queen of Clubs
Queen of Diamonds
Three of Diamonds
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me play around with this and see where it takes me.